# Android dynamically add EditText in Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext

I'm stuck trying to add an editText field dynamically under my existing editText fields using a button. Currently pressing the button does nothing. Here is my code:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d4cfcd">
tools:context="com.zdowning.decisionmaker.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Your Question Here"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDecisions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Answer #2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Answer #1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Enter Answer #3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/remove_button"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="DECIDE!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Java:**

```
package com.zdowning.decisionmaker;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

import java.lang.*;

import static com.zdowning.decisionmaker.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int numberOfLines = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(activity_main);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             getAnswer();
        }
    });

    final Button Add_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Add_Line();
        }
    });
}


public void Add_Line() {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutDecisions);

    // add edittext
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setId(numberOfLines + 1);
    ll.addView(et);
    numberOfLines++;
}


public void getAnswer() {
    String[] options = new String[3];

    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    options[0] = text.getText().toString();

    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    options[1] = text.getText().toString();

    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    options[2] = text.getText().toString();

    int number = (int)(Math.random() * 3);
    String answer = options[number];

    TextView answerBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    answerBox.setText(answer);
}
}
```

Any advice would be a huge help as I'm brand new to android studio. Coding what is above took me hours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your `Add_line()` method to :

```
 public void Add_Line() {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutDecisions);
    // add edittext
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    et.setLayoutParams(p);
    et.setText("Text");
    et.setId(numberOfLines + 1);
    ll.addView(et);
    numberOfLines++;
}
```

add the `LayoutParams` to the `Edittext`

Comment: @JamaicanMeCode if the answer helps, mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the answer..thnakx

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the best solution

Comment: suppose I add control two times at that time how can I get the value of both edit text right now I am just getting the last one value of edit text.

Answer (score 3):

> This help someone who want to add dynamic TextInputLayout to linear
>   layout.

```
 LinearLayout linearLayoutSubParent = new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setWeightSum(100f); // you can also add more widget by providing weight

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutSubParentParams =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100f);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutSubParentParams);
        linearLayoutSubParent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Add TextInputLayout to parent layout first
        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textInputLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 100f);


        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(textInputLayoutParams);
        textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.TextSizeHint);
        linearLayoutSubParent.addView(textInputLayout);

        // Add EditText control to TextInputLayout
        final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        editTextParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);

        editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size));
        editText.setHint("Enter value");
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS);
        editText.setEnabled(false);

        textInputLayout.addView(editText, editTextParams);


        linearLayoutParent.addView(linearLayoutSubParent);

 <style name="TextSizeHint" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
 </style>

 <dimen name="text_size">20dp</dimen>
```